# Text Selection Covers entire width of screen

Tags: html, css

Whenever I select/highlight text on my website, the bar overlaps everything on my page.

[image: Text Selction]

(Text selection box isn't actually grey, just needed to capture screenshot) How can I stop it from doing this so it stays in the white box?

The white box the text is in uses " word-wrap: break-word " to stop the text from overlapping the white box. I don't know if the problem is related to this or not.

```
<p> Test Test Test Test Test </p>

p {                         
font-family: "Calibri";
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-size: 18px;
color: black; }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS in the post, so we can inspect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add style `oveflow: hidden;` for child div.
Find the below example

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{
    background: #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}
.content{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/65ohobaL/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same effect by using `position: relative` on the parent element as long as the parent element isn't the full width of the page.

For example, if you have

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p> Test Test Test Test Test </p>
</div>
```

In your CSS you can put

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 700px; // set this to width you want your content to be
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

And you will get the same effect. The background of the selected text will only be as width as the `.wrapper` element.